# Dropdown and Route Issues

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamically populated navbar from JSON data in angularJS.

I have six tabs in navbar which comes from JSON data:

- Now when I press the 1st tab there is a `1st.html` file which will load to div. This is done using `ngRoute`.
- 2nd tab and 3rd tab works similar to work as per expectation. 4th tab is a dropdown.
- On 4th Tab: Hover dropdown is displayed, but when clicked behind dropdown the route is directed to home because of redirect route option. If the navgiation was like from 3rd tab the user click 4th tab the dropdown should be displayed and active class should be 3rd Tab container.

Please help. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you share a code example? That should help us understand what is going on.

Comment: @AlexJohnson      Code is completely junk.... Requirement is There are two tabs HOME & DROPDOWN when I click HOME tab HOME.html will load to ng-view and when I click DROPDOWN tab I need dropdown to be displayed and ng-view should have HOME data only. ngRoute routes to home page when home is clicked. for dropdown no ngRoute and the home page should be displayed and dropdown list on top of home page

Answer (score 0):

I think the only trick to make it work is that you have to manually bootstrap AngularJS because you need to load the data before config phase.

You can do an ajax request in `domready` handler to load your routing data and add it to your Angular configuration in the success callback.
Then you can bootstrap the app by calling `angular.bootstrap`. (No `ng-app` in html markup needed.)

The structure of my `routesJson` is the minimum you need to get it working. There are no nested routes for the dropdown routes. (But I think that's OK.)

You can use the `routesJson` to create the html markup with `ng-repeat` and also use it for `ngRoute` configuration. I've added it to a service so it's easier to access with-out a global variable. (At the first version of the demo, I started with the commented `var routesJson = [{}]` global.)

Something like in the demo below or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/52mk64jd/) should be doing what you're looking for.

```js
/*var routesJson = [{
 id: 0,
    name: 'home',
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    caption: 'Home',
    controllerAs: 'homeCtrl',
    controller: function($scope) {
     $scope.hello = 'hello from homeCtrl scope';
        this.hello = 'hello from homeCtrl';
    }
},
{
 id: 1,
    name: 'first',
    url: '/first/',
    templateUrl: '1st.html',
    caption: '1st item'
},
{
 id: 2,
    name: 'dropdown',
    caption: 'Dropdown',
    nested: [{
     id: 0,
        url: '/dashboard/',
        name: 'dashboard',
        caption: 'Dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
    }]
}];*/

angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap'])
 .provider('routesData', function() {
     var routesData = [];
        
        this.setRoutes = function(routes) {
         routesData = routes;
        }
        
     this.$get = function() {
         return new RoutesDataService(routesData);
        }
    })
 .controller('mainController', MainController);
    
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
 // loading json config on dom ready and manually bootstrap angular
 $.ajax({
        url: "https://www.mocky.io/v2/5755df7b1300004f318ea48b",

        // The name of the callback parameter, as specified by the YQL service
        jsonp: "callback",

        // Tell jQuery we're expecting JSONP
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(jsonData) {
            var routesJson = jsonData;
            
            angular.module('demoApp')
             .config(routesConfig);

   function routesConfig($routeProvider, routesDataProvider) {
                var url, templateUrl, route;
                //console.log('add config', $routeProvider);
                //console.log('routes', routesJson);
                // add the routes to routesData service
                routesDataProvider.setRoutes(routesJson);
                
                // load routes to $routeProvider
                loadRoutes(routesJson);

                function addRoute(url, route) {
                    $routeProvider.when(url, {
                        templateUrl: route.templateUrl,
                        controller: route.controller,
                        controllerAs: route.controllerAs
                    });
                }

                function loadRoutes(routes) {
                    for (var i=0; i < routes.length; i++) {
                        route = routes[i];
                        url = route.url;
                        if (!route.nested) {
                            templateUrl = route.templateUrl;
                            if ( url ) {
                                addRoute(url, route);
                            }
                        } else {
                            //console.log('nested')
                            // nested route or only a dropdown route
                            // --> no nesting in the demo just top-level routes
                            var nestedRoute;
                            for(var j=0; j<route.nested.length; j++) {
                                nestedRoute = route.nested[j];
                                addRoute(nestedRoute.url, nestedRoute);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $routeProvider.otherwise({
                        redirectTo: "/"
                    });
                }
            }

            // manual bootstrapping
            //setTimeout(function() { 
            // add timeout for testing loading spinner
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['demoApp']);
            //}, 4000);
        }
    });
});

function RoutesDataService(routes) {
 var factory = {
     routes: [] // we could add defaults here
    };
    
    angular.extend(factory, {
     routes: routes
    });
    
    return factory;
}

function MainController($location, $http, routesData) {
 var vm = this;
    vm.loaded = true;
    vm.routesJson = routesData.routes;
    vm.isActive = function(url) {
     return ($location.url() === url);
    };    
}
```

```css
.nav .btn {
    /* fix paddin in tab nav*/
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

/* spinner css created with
http://cssload.net/en/spinners/8 */

.wrapper {
 padding-left: 1em;
 padding-right: 1em;
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
 width: 195px;
}

.cssload-loader {
 width: 49px;
 height: 49px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 3em;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.cssload-loader {
 width: 49px;
 height: 49px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: 3em;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.cssload-loader,
.cssload-loader:before,
.cssload-loader:after {
 animation: 1.15s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: 1.15s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: 1.15s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: 1.15s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: 1.15s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.cssload-loader:before,
.cssload-loader:after {
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.cssload-loader:before,
.cssload-loader:after {
  content: "";
}

.cssload-loader:before,
.cssload-loader:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  animation: cssload-animation 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: cssload-animation 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
  -ms-animation: cssload-animation 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation: cssload-animation 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: cssload-animation 1.73s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.cssload-loader:after { animation-delay: 0.86s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.86s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 0.86s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.86s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.86s; }



@keyframes cssload-animation {
 0%  { transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0); }
 50% { transform: translateX(0%)  scale(1); }
 100% { transform: translateX(100%) scale(0); }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-animation {
 0%  { -o-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0); }
 50% { -o-transform: translateX(0%)  scale(1); }
 100% { -o-transform: translateX(100%) scale(0); }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-animation {
 0%  { -ms-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0); }
 50% { -ms-transform: translateX(0%)  scale(1); }
 100% { -ms-transform: translateX(100%) scale(0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-animation {
 0%  { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0); }
 50% { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%)  scale(1); }
 100% { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%) scale(0); }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-animation {
 0%  { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%) scale(0); }
 50% { -moz-transform: translateX(0%)  scale(1); }
 100% { -moz-transform: translateX(100%) scale(0); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular-route.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="app" ng-controller="mainController as mainCtrl">
    <div class="wrapper" ng-hide="mainCtrl.loaded">
        <div class="cssload-loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-cloak>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-class="{active: mainCtrl.isActive(navItem.url)}"ng-repeat="navItem in mainCtrl.routesJson">
                <a ng-href="#{{navItem.url}}" ng-if="!navItem.nested">{{navItem.caption}}</a>
                <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown ng-if="navItem.nested">
                    <a class="btn btn-default" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                    {{navItem.caption}}<span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                        <li role="menuitem" ng-class="{active: mainCtrl.isActive(subNav.url)}" ng-repeat="subNav in navItem.nested"><a ng-href="#{{subNav.url}}">{{subNav.caption}}</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
          <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>-->
        </ul>
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
  </div>
    
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
   <h1>home</h1>
    {{hello}}<br/>
    {{homeCtrl.hello}}<br/>
    <a href="#/dashboard">dashboard</a>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="1st.html">
   <h1>first</h1>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dashboard.html">
   <h1>dashboard</h1>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used ngx-bootstrap over here, You can remove # of the toggle link the reason is it will consider as a link

```
<ul *ngIf="loggedIn()" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">        
        <li class="dropdown" dropdown>
        **// remove href**
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle >
            Welcome {{_authService.decodeToken?.unique_name | titlecase}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>           
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Or you can do add click event false

```
 <li (click) = "false" class="dropdown" dropdown>
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdownToggle >
            Welcome {{_authService.decodeToken?.unique_name | titlecase}}
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" *dropdownMenu>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Profile</a></li>           
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a (click)="logout()"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```